# Content/icons in BottomNaviationView not showing

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, kotlin

I am trying to implement a simple bottom navigation bar on my android app using the Material Design library.  I looked at tutorials and several other sites and Medium articles, and the code seems pretty simple/boilerplate; however, the icons in my bottom navigation bar do not seem to exist (given that setting (layout_height = wrap_content makes the entire bar shrink to nothing).

I am not sure why the bottom nav bar appears to be empty or not show anything.

[image: activity_main.xml]

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            />
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

bottom_nav.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item

        android:id="@+id/nav_rest"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rest_nav"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Restaurant-List"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_maps"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_location_24dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Map"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
        android:title="Menu"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cart_24dp"
        android:title="nav_cart"
        />
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `ConstraintLayout` when you really want a simple `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`?

Comment: No, I am very new to android development.  I used constraint layout because I had some familiarity with it and I had read that it helps keep the xml flatter.  I tried changing it to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` as well as `Relative Layout`, but it did not change anything.  I am basically looking for a simple e-commerce style app with a bottom nav bar to navigate to different fragments with RecycleView + CardView to scroll through a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity_main.xml :RecyclerView

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 android:layout_width="400dp"
```

should be

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_bar"
android:layout_width="0dp"
```